# How to install codecs for H.264 in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, h.264

We need to play some ***H.264/AAC*** videos in Winforms project written in C#. This should run on ***Windows XP SP2*** and ***Linux*** (using Mono). In order to be able to do that, the computer has to have appropriate codecs installed I guess. Does anybody know if there is a way of installing the codecs as a part of installation of our project using msi installer. Is there some free or paid component, which we can use? Ideally in a form of some dll which, we could just register to the system somehow. Or is there some better way?

**UPDATE:**
We have found this: http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/ It is not ideal so far, but we will try to investigate more.

Comment: IANAL, but: Windows should include the required codecs with Media Player, and they *might* be available for use for third-party applications deployed on Windows. On Linux, to be completely legit, you should licence the decoder yourself. (I believe you can use any implementation you wish when you do.) There is **no such thing** as a completely free-of-charge h264 library. The algorithms themselves are patented, and you owe royalties to the MPEG-LA no matter which implementation you use.

Comment: That said, there are use cases which are exempt from royalties. (Like, famously, web browsers for playing back streaming web video.) It's also possible that someone else covers the licence fee for you. (As should be the the case with Windows and OS X, they do the same for the TrueType patents.) This *may* be the decoder library implementer, but it's pretty unlikely that library would be free. A decoder library vendor may also charge additional licence fees for their implementation above the patent licence.

Comment: From the volume of verbiage above you can ascertain that you should be consulting a lawyer.

Comment: Why don't you just allow the user to handle installing the codecs?  Provide a link to the codecs and have them install it.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunetly we can not let users to install the codecs by themselves. It is a requirment from the bussines perspective from the very beginning.

Comment: @millimoose thanks for the legal stuff. We will seek some legal counsel. However, I was hoping that somebody will know about some paid component for playing H.264 videos, which can be used easily in .NET.

Comment: @OndraPeterka [This Engadget article](http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/04/know-your-rights-h-264-patent-licensing-and-you/) implies no such thing might exist: "In any event, MPEG-LA has said to us that only the parties at the top and bottom of the H.264 tool chain are generally required to pay royalties; that is, the party who makes the encoder, and the party who distributes the encoded file to the end users. You can think of that as the first and last transaction, if you like -- the person who sells the encoder and the person who sells the content are the ones who have to pay."

Comment: @OndraPeterka So, as I understand it, you can't have a third party provide you with a licence to commercially distribute h.264 video. (I might understand it horribly, since the whole thing is confusing to normal people. My point is that it's entirely possible the simple solution you wish for may or may not exist, hence, ask a lawyer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we used this library: http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com/, which proofs to be exactly what we need. We can play videos and auidos encoded in H.264/AAC codecs on every system (Win7, Win8, XP and various distribution of Linux), with very quite small effort now.

Answer (score 3):

The MPEG-4 codecs are not free (MPEG LA licensing terms apply) in first place, so the first thing is to find what exactly codecs you are going to redistribute, and check this SDK/with this vendor how to correctly install and redistribute their software.

You will find some codec implementations listed here on Wikipedia:

- [AVC software implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Software_encoder_feature_comparison)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I was hoping for some .NET targeted solution. E.g. some component with customizable video player with all the codecs needed.